# Referencing a field by its ID instead of expanding it

Tags: java, simple-framework

I am new to the Simple framework for XML (Java) and ran into a problem serializing specific class constructs.

I have two classes:

```
@Root(name="static")
class StaticData {
  @Attribute
  private String id;
  @Attribute
  private String value;
 ...
}
```

and

```
@Root(name="listdata")
class ListData {
  // Problem field
  @Attribute
  private StaticData ref;
  @Element
  private String name;
}
```

And receive
"*TransformException: Transform of class StaticData not supported*".
I want the ref-field in ListData not to expand into the static data XML structure (then @Element would be fine), but to get a reference.

```
<listdata ref="foo">
  <name>bla bla</name>
</listdata>
```

where "foo" is a valid value for "id" in some StaticData object already loaded in my application.

In JAXB I would use the XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation

```
@XmlAttribute(name="id")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyStaticDataAdapter.class)
```

but I cannot seem to find a working equivalent in Simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In doubt you can use a ***Converter*** to implement such a behaviour.

**Here's an example:**

```
@Root(name = "listdata")
@Convert(ListData.ListDataConverter.class)
class ListData
{
    @Attribute
    private StaticData ref;
    @Element
    private String name;

    // ...

    // Converter implementation
    static class ListDataConverter implements Converter<ListData>
    {

        @Override
        public ListData read(InputNode node) throws Exception
        {
            /*
             * In case you also want to read, implement this too ...
             */
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        public void write(OutputNode node, ListData value) throws Exception
        {
            node.setAttribute("ref", value.ref.getId());
            node.getChild("name").setValue(value.name);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Serializer ser = new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy());
                            /* ^----- important! -----^ */

ListData ld = ...
ser.write(ld, System.out); // Serialize to std out
```

**Output**

With these `ListData` values ...

- name = abcdefg
- ref = ...

  - id = 123
  - value = this is a value

you'll get ...

```
<listdata ref="123">
   <name>def</name>
</listdata>
```

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for. 
I already tried around with my own Converter, but I tried implementing it for StaticData instead of ListData - which failed.

Comment: One drawback. There are two options to use a Converter in ListData - globally for the whole class or just for a single field.
If applied to the whole class, I have to take care of *ALL* other fields as well, which would normally produce good results. There doesn't seem to be a default behavior.

If I use it for the single field, I still get the same error.

Comment: If you use a converter for a field, you have to apply `@Element` to it to. Eg. `@Element @Convert(WhatEver.class) <field>`. But i'm not sure if you can access the parent Xml node then.

Comment: Tried that already. This creates - not surprisingly - an element of the name and offers the element node to the converter. But I don't want a extra element - I want to influence how the field is converted to an attribute.
As a workaround I tried using @Element for the field, than in the Converter access node.getParent().addAttribute(...) and a node.remove() to remove the unwanted element, but the parent node was already commited.

Seems I am stuck to having a converter for the whole class. At least that works.

Comment: You can file a bug for this, for me this use case sounds really useful. Btw. you can use a Serializer to serialize the fields to the outputnode, this will reduce the effort.

Comment: Just found out somebody open a feature request for this over a year ago: http://sourceforge.net/p/simple/feature-requests/22/
Also someone opened a bug ticket for Converter not working for Attribute: http://sourceforge.net/p/simple/bugs/34/